# What is TSource in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

**Question**

What is `TSource`?

Here is an [example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx):

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Union<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    IEnumerable<TSource> second,
    IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer
)
```

Is it a type? Couldn't find any MSDN documentation on it. I assume it can't be a type since I couldn't click on it in [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/).

Is it a .NET keyword? Didn't find it in the [C# keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) list.

Is it something the .NET compiler interprets in a special way?

**What I already know**

I know that `T` is a generic type parameter which is used sort of as a placeholder in a generic method. Example from [What Are Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#csharp_generics_topic2) from MSDN:

```
public class Stack<T>
{
   T[] m_Items; 
   public void Push(T item)
   {...}
   public T Pop()
   {...}
}
Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
stack.Push(1);
stack.Push(2);
int number = stack.Pop();
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`TSource` is just a *generic type parameter*. You can tell that because it comes in angle brackets after the method name in the declaration:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Union<TSource>
```

You can use *any* identifier for a type parameter name, so this would be equally valid:

```
public static IEnumerable<Foo> Union<Foo>
```

Conventionally, however, either `T` or a name beginning with `T` is used. In this cases, it's indicating the type of the "source" element of the union. LINQ methods typically use the following type parameter names:

- `TSource`: element type of the input (source)
- `TResult`: element type of the output (result)
- `TKey`: element type of a key used for things like grouping
- `TElement`: element type of an intermediate sequence - this is more rarely used, but it appears in [some overloads of GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535049.aspx) and similar methods

Comment: Your comment "You can use *any* identifier for a type parameter name" made the light bulb light up. Thank you.

Comment: @Lernkurve: Glad to be of service :)

Comment: So it's T by convention :) Thats all I needed for understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

`TSource` is the same as `T` just named differently to be more descriptive

You can see more examples of this in `Func<T, TResult>` and numerous other generic classes.  Here is a quick naming convention for generics from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479858.aspx#bestpractices_topic2).

> Name generic type parameters with
>   descriptive names, unless a single
>   letter name is completely self
>   explanatory and a descriptive name
>   would not add value.

```
public interface ISessionChannel<TSession> 
{...}
public delegate TOutput Converter<TInput,TOutput>(TInput from);
```

Answer (score 5):

It is a generics parameter for a type. `TSource` is just the name to "be replaced with a real type". All `TSource` must be replaced with the same type.

If you have

```
public static bool Foo<T1, T2>(
    T1 item1,
    T2 item2,
    T1 item3,
    T2 item4,
)
```

then `item1` and `item3` must of of the same type, `item2` and `item4` must be of the same type. But `item1` and `item2` does not have to be of the same type.

Answer (score 4):

TSource is equivalent to T. When having more than one generic type it's better to name them in a "readable" manner rather than using single letters.

For example, for the .NET type of Func, the MSDN docs have the example of "`Func<T, TResult>`". Naming the generic parameter in this way makes it easier for you to know what you should be expecting  from the object.

Answer (score 3):

TSource is like T, only called TSource. They could have called U, V, Z. They called it TSource.

Answer (score 3):

`TSource` is just a more meaningful name instead of `T`. This is needed, because classes and methods can have more than one type parameter (and a method can have a different one than the class, ofc.), ie. `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<TSource>
```

**T** means Type. The type you want to use here.